# My ionic2 config.xml file turns empty after use .What could be the reason?

Tags: ionic2

How to solve ionic2 error? In ionic2 project my config.xml file is empty.
Before 5 minute it was working fine but suddenly start giving error, on check my config.xml file I see it's empty. It's giving me the following error

```
D:\ionic projects\01 initial\version1>cordova run android
Parsing D:\ionic projects\01 initial\version1\config.xml failed
Error: Unexpected end
Line: 0
Column: 0
Char:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create new project , 
coppy that file from here
and then build project again